# MySQL max value from subquery and group by problem

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I have three tables which we'll pretend are called products, coupons, and discounts. I have a query that attempts to pull a list of products, and runs a subquery to find ANY coupons which have a valid discount.

For example, this shows what I'm attempting:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, 
 (
 SELECT MAX(discounts.amount) FROM discounts
 WHERE discounts.coupon_id = coupons.id
 LIMIT 1
 ) as discount
FROM products
LEFT JOIN coupons ON products.id = coupons.product_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

My problem is that my GROUP BY is necessary for lots of other reasons. But if there are multiple coupons for each product, the "discount" gets combined in weird ways when the grouping occurs.

Let's say for a single product there are three coupons - two without any discount and one with a discount of 33%. When the group by occurs, I want to choose the highest value but by default, MySQL returns the value as 0.

Using MAX is the subquery obviously only returns the maximim value of discounts for each individual coupon. I just need to tell GROUP BY to use the max value.

I could easily use GROUP_CONCAT to return a string of all of them, but I also need to use that value in a calculation in some HAVING conditions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't think you want or need the subquery. What does this return for you?

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, MAX(discounts.amount) AS discount
FROM products
LEFT JOIN coupons ON products.id = coupons.product_id
LEFT JOIN discounts ON coupons.id = discounts.coupon_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as easy as this. I would have use joins but there are actually four subqueries - each checking for a different type of possible discount. It didn't seem possible for me to structure the joins in a way that wouldn't require each product to have all four joins. The subqueries make that condition easier/possible. I guess I'll play with those more.

Answer (score 0):

You group by productid only, while the subselect actually return three values (one for each coupon of the product). I would actually expect this query to return an error. You should either move the discount one level up, or move the coupons to the subselect. An example of the first (subqueries are typically slower in MySQL):

```
select
  p.productid,
  max(d.discount) as discount
from
  product p
  left join coupon c on c.productid = p.productid
  left join discount d on d.couponid = c.couponid
group by
  p.productid
```